# How to manually instrument my nextjs 13 application

Tags: next.js

`I am instrumenting my nextjs app with typescript manually and following the steps according to the documentation: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/manual/

This is my tracing.ts:

```
import { BatchSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base";
import { Resource } from "@opentelemetry/resources";
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions";
import { WebTracerProvider } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web";
import { registerInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation";

registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [],
});

const resource =
  Resource.default().merge(
    new Resource({
      [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: "TOTA",
      [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_VERSION]: "0.1.0",
    })
  );

const exporter = new ConsoleSpanExporter();
const processor = new BatchSpanProcessor(exporter);

const webProvider = new WebTracerProvider({
  resource: resource,
});

webProvider.addSpanProcessor(processor);
webProvider.register();
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "ts-node --require ./lib/tracing.ts next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.3",
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.7.7",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.8.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.8.0",
    "@next/font": "13.4.4",
    "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.4.1",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation": "^0.40.0",
    "@opentelemetry/resources": "^1.14.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node": "^1.14.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web": "^1.14.0",
    "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "^1.14.0",
    "@types/node": "20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.8",
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "formik": "^2.4.1",
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.11",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

I don't see the trace on Jaeger. I want to clarify that I already have opentelemetry configured, both receiver and exports, Jaeger for traces.This is my code where I create the trace, in the userEffect:

```
'use client'

import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridActionsCellItem,
  GridRowParams,
  GridToolbar 
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

import { ProfileReducer } from '../../reducers/ProfileReducer'
import useFireStore from '../../../hooks/useFireStore'

import opentelemetry from "@opentelemetry/api";

const init = () => {
    let data: any = [];
    return data;
};

export default function GetProfiles(){

    const router = useRouter();
    const { data: session, status } = useSession({
        required: false, 
        onUnauthenticated(){
            router.push("/login");
        }
    });

    const {getAllDocuments, deleteDocument} = useFireStore();
    const [profiles, dispatch] = useReducer(ProfileReducer, [], init);

    const handleDeleteClick = (id: string) => () => {
        deleteDocument("profiles", id);

        let profile:any = {
            id: id
        };
        let action:any = {
            type: "delete",
            payload: profile
        };

        if(dispatch){
            dispatch(action);
        }
    };

    const tracer = opentelemetry.trace.getTracer(
        'GetProfilesComponente'
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const spanProfiles = tracer.startSpan('profiles');
        spanProfiles.addEvent('Profiles');
        getAllDocuments("profiles").then(data => {
            data.map(x => {
                let action = {
                    type: "create",
                    payload: {
                        id: x.id,
                        firstName: x.data.firstName,
                        lastName: x.data.lastName,
                        email: x.data.email,
                        birthdate: new Date(x.data.birthdate)
                    }
                };
                dispatch(action);
            });
            spanProfiles.end();
        });
    }, []);

    const columns: GridColDef[] = [
        { 
            field: 'firstName', 
            headerName: 'First Name', 
            type: 'string',  
            width: 200, 
            align: 'left',
            headerAlign: 'left',
            editable: false
        },
        {
            field: 'lastName',
            headerName: 'Last Name',
            type: 'string',
            width: 200,
            align: 'left',
            headerAlign: 'left',
            editable: false,
        },
        {
            field: 'email',
            headerName: 'Email',
            type: 'email',
            width: 300,
            align: 'left',
            headerAlign: 'left',
            editable: false,
        },
        {
            field: 'birthdate',
            headerName: 'Birthdate',
            type: 'date',
            width: 150,
            align: 'left',
            headerAlign: 'left',
            editable: false,
        },
        {
          field: 'actions',
          type: 'actions',
          headerName: 'Actions',
          width: 100,
          cellClassName: 'actions',
          getActions: (params: GridRowParams) => {
            const id = params['id'] as string;
            return [
              <GridActionsCellItem
                icon={<DeleteIcon />}
                label="Delete"
                onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
                color="inherit"
              />,
            ];
          },
        },
      ];

    return(
        <Box style={{ padding: 20 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid lg={3}></Grid>
                <Grid lg={6}>
                    <Box
                        sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                        <DataGrid
                            rows={profiles}
                            columns={columns}
                            initialState={{
                                pagination: {
                                    paginationModel: {
                                        pageSize: 5,
                                    },
                                },
                            }}
                            pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20]}
                            slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}/>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
                <Grid lg={3}></Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

I hope you can guide me since I am new to implementing the tool and if necessary, correct me if there is something wrong that I have done in what I have shown. If you need more details of what I have done, just ask me so I can add it to the post.